# Error on Heroku when trying to post data ( error:0909006C Pem routines..._

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, heroku, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a small nodeJS server deployed on Heroku, saving data to Firestore database. The server is deployed and running correctly.
I use Insomnia to test my requests and when I use it locally I can send a post request and save my data object to the database without issues. However, when I try to send a post request to Heroku, I get a 500 error with this message:

> {     "code": 16,     "details": "Failed to retrieve auth metadata with
> error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line",
> "metadata": {},     "note": "Exception occurred in retry method that was
> not classified as transient" }

I have read that it is necessary to add real line breaks in the env variable but I guess I am doing it already. This is my `initializeApp` function:

```
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
        projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
        privateKey: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
        ? process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/gm, "\n")
        : undefined,
        clientEmail: process.env.CLIENT_EMAIL
      }),
    databaseURL: "XXXXX"
  });
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by copy-pasting the key with break lines directly into Heroku config variables and removing `.replace(/\\n/gm, "\n")` from the code.

```
privateKey: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
    ? process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
    : undefined
```